# Surface rendered with a different blur frame by frame

Tags: animation, glass, depth-of-field

I'm using Blender 2.79 to render an animation. While many frames look consistent, every three or four frames, a series of frames crop up where a surface is rendered differently than the rest, often with what appears to be a depth of field blur in a different place. See the differences frame by frame with the ground surface here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first image is correct and the rest not correct.

I'm using a camera with a cube as a depth of field focus object, if that matters. Also using denoising, which doesn't seem to be the issue, and the fracture modifier for destruction. There is only one light in the scene that does not move.

Any hope for making the frames more consistent?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "crop up". Do you mean that a specific glass shard isn't in focus as it's supposed to? Do you have the depth of field focus object at a static location or is it animated as well?

Comment: The depth of field focus object is static. The glass shards appear as expected; it's the floor that isn't consistent frame to frame. It's as if parts of the floor are flickering in and out of focus. See the difference in the rendering of the floor from frame to frame above.

Comment: I see what you mean. What is that catching the reflection on the floor in the first render a texture or simulated water?

Comment: The floor has a texture fed into the Normal of an Anisotropic BSDF as well as the material's displacement. That's what the "scratched" effect is on the floor. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I'm not sure what's causing this. Do you have caustics enabled? Does it make a difference when it's disabled?

Comment: I disabled Reflective Caustics and Refractive Caustics with no improvement on the problematic frames. Filter Glossy was at 0.5—checking to see if it helps to bring it down to 0. I attached the .blend.

Comment: Zeroing out Filter Glossy does nothing! So strange.

Comment: If you re-render affected frames with a different sampling seed, does the effect disappear/ change? Could it just be unlucky samples on something that is hard to hit?

Comment: I could reproduce the problem in 2.79b, but it doesn't seem to happen in Blender 2.8.

Comment: Changing the sampling seed doesn't seem to help. I found a Windows version of Blender 2.8 with fracture modifier, but it didn't maintain my fracture settings. Did you find a solution that maintains a 2.79 fracture modifier, @rjg ?

Comment: No, sorry I don't. If you're up to a little tinkering, you could render the glass in 2.79b and composite with the sequence of the ground rendered in 2.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the issue was, it was resolved by re-rendering the whole project with [a version of Blender 2.8 with Fracture Modifier](https://blender.community/c/graphicall/Lcbbbc/) (rather than 2.79b). Thanks to rjg for the suggestion!